# how to change font awesome icon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script

```
<audio src="http://193.108.24.21:8000/fresh" id="audio"></audio>
    <i class='fas fa-play fa-5x' id="play" onclick="play(this)"></i>

    <script>
    function play(button) {
    var audio = $(button).prev()[0];
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        $('#play').removeClass('fa-play')
        $('#play').addClass('fa-pause')
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
        $('#play').addClass('fa-play')
        $('#play').removeClass('fa-pause')
    }
}
    </script>
```

but when I add several to one page it doesn't work.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2EZa.png)

This is what happens, each player works for itself, but the icons do not.
When one player is clicked, only one icon changes as in the picture

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuGRe.png)

How can I make each icon stand out for itself?
I changed the id for each one individually but it didn't happen again.
Thanks!

Comment: `but when I add several to one page it doesn't work.` ... because you probably add "several" with the same id of `play` ... how will the script know which one you mean? ... why not use `$(button)` instead of `$('#play')`

Comment: please give all icons an unique id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  $(button) instead of $("#play") to target the clicked button instead of an id, which won't work because it's not unique.

```
    <script>
    function play(button) {
    var audio = $(button).prev()[0];
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        $(button).removeClass('fa-play')
        $(button).addClass('fa-pause')
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
        $(button).addClass('fa-play')
        $(button).removeClass('fa-pause')
    }
}
    </script>
```

also you could use .toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause') instead of adding and removing the classes manually.